# Cells are not showing date as per Format in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my excel sheet, I have selected date in Format Cells as 3/14/01 (which is M/DD/YY)

Some cells in DATE column are showing date in correct format like 5/31/12 (M/DD/YY), while some are showing it as 31/5/12 (D/MM/YY).

When I select any Date Cell from dale column, it shows 1/6/12, date on top data entry section appear as 06/01/2012

See attached pic for more info on this weired issue.

Any suggestion please?

[image]

Comment: Check if those cell values are actually datetime values, or strings

Answer (score 1):

Excel is looking for a 4 digit year.  Replace the two digit 5/31/12 with 5/31/2012 and see what happens.

The other thing that happens is Excel looks to see what the regional date settings are and tries to match them.  When I changed my regional settings for the date, Excel updated accordingly.

Under Windows 7.  Right click the date under the taskbar and choose Adjust Date/Time.  Change Date and Time.  Change Calendar Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a discrepancy between your control panel Windows Regional settings, and how you are entering the dates.  So some (those where m>12) will get interpreted as text and appear to display OK, other will be converted to dates but probably not the way you wish.  Either `enter` your dates according to your windows short-date format, or `IMPORT` your file, using the text import wizard to properly assign the date input format.